# Derive the ellipse equation starting with a definition of eccentricity

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, classical-mechanics

I am trying to derive the equation for an ellipse (given in the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oftb2.png) and in my [attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2hzb.jpg) (the red equation)) using the given information in the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oftb2.png). I don't know how to relate **d** in my [attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2hzb.jpg) to the variables given in the problem. I think I am on the right track though. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The origin is at the focus, not at the centre of the ellipse.

Comment: Do you mean theta should be measured from p upwards? How does that describe an ellipse?

Comment: Not "from p" but from the point of the ellipse (let's call it $A$) which is nearest to the focus and with centre $F$, i.e. for any point $P$ on the ellipse: $\theta =\angle AFP$ and $r=FP$. For instance, point $W$ in your attempt has $r=p$ and $\theta=-90°$.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_focus